Безопасно ли использовать библиотеку ниже стандартом?
Например, мой код компилируется компилятором со стандартом c++20. При этом использует библиотеку (не header-only), скомпилированную тем же компилятором, но со стандартом c++17. Безопасно ли это?

Что есть "безопасность" в вашем понимании применительно к этой ситуации?

@Kromster ну, могут ли возникнуть какие-то проблемы из-за этого? Креши, ошибки компиляции/линковки, UB и т.п. в будущем

Вот это уточнение в тело вопроса вносите пожалуйста, кнопка "править"

В целом должно быть безопасно.
Хотя third-party библиотеки могут понаписать у себя в хедерах такого, что это не будет работать (проверить версию стандарта через #if __cplusplus == ..., и воткнуть разный код для разных версий), это редкость, и по хорошему должно быть написано жирным шрифтом в мануале.

Безусловно можно использовать библиотеки, написанные на разных стандартах языка. Более того, можно даже использовать разные языки. Главное, что нужно обеспечить при этом - совместимость на уровне ABI. Т.е. Application Binary Interface.
Если речь идёт о разных версиях одного компилятора, или даже об одной и той же версии компилятора, но кода, собранного с указанием различных C++ стандартов, то надо смотреть на таблицу совместимостей ABI. Например, для MSVC заявлено, что для MSVC 2015 и новее такая совместимость есть. Про gcc можно почитать тут.

Много текста по gcc ссылке. Так и не понял, для одной и той же версии gcc, компилирующая с -std=c++17 библиотека с -std=c++20 кодом совместимы (остальные опции одинаковые)?

@borg, вообще-то, все вопросы совместимости проще выявить в ходе тестирования

@avp если у меня сегодня всё работает, то это не значит что завтра авторы библиотеки не добавят что-то из-за чего у меня всё поломается. Хотелось бы узнать возможно ли это

@borg, да, при изменении установленных в ОС shared libraries все может сломаться. Поэтому при эксплуатации серьезных приложений их обязательно надо перетестировать при любых планируемых изменениях окружения
